# Accessing context of a closure in python

Tags: python

Consider some trivial closure:

```
def foo(an_argument, a_kw_argument=10):
    a = 10

    def bar():
        print(a)

    print('locals dict:', locals())
    return bar
```

In the above code, one can see the `locals()` dict printed out, which describes the local context of the `bar()` function. How can I view that local context from inside the closure?

My rudimentary understanding is that it is represented through a cell object attached to `bar`, but I can't see how to make use of that from the python world.

In practice, I don't want to view the context inside the function *per se*, but I want to handle it through a decorator. The point of this is about using python for meta-programming.